# No query results for model [User] | laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a newbie to Laravel so I'm not yet familiar with the errors it's returning, I hope someone can help me with this.

So I created a simple app with registration form and a login form and the registered user can post whatever he/she wants but I'm getting this error

This is the form where the user can post:

```
@section('content')

    <section class="header">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile')}}" class="new">Back to Profile</a></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
    <div class="newpost">
        <h3>What new today?</h3><br>
        <form action="{{URL::route('createPost')}}" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title..." required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Write Report</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" placeholder="Write Here..." rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn2">Publish</button>

    </form>
    </div>
@stop
```

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/Newpost', array(
    'uses' => 'LoginUsersController@newPost',
    'as' => 'newPost'
    ));

Route::post('/CreatePost/{id}', array(
    'uses' => 'LoginUsersController@createPost',
    'as' => 'createPost'
    ));

and the controller

public function createPost($id)
    {
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);

        $post = array(
            'title' => Input::get('title'),
            'content' => Input::get('content')
            );
        $posts = new Post($post);
        $user->post()->save($post);

        dd($post);
    }
```

and the User model where I'm guessing is causing the error.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $fillable = array('email', 'password');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function getRememberToken() 
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }


    public function setRememberToken($value) 
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }


    public function getRememberTokenName() 
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function Post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain to me why I'm getting this error? Thanks

Comment: You might want to add the tag laravel to your question

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because `findOrFail` can't find anything. So it *fails*.
If your route depends on the users id. You actually have to pass it along when creating your form:

```
<form action="{{URL::route('createPost', Auth::id())}}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

(`Auth::id()` retrieves the id of the current logged in user)

However instead, I suggest that you remove the user id from the `createPost` route and work with the currently logged in user directly in the controller:

```
Route::post('/CreatePost', array(
    'uses' => 'LoginUsersController@createPost',
    'as' => 'createPost'
));
```

And then:

```
public function createPost()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $post = array(
        'title' => Input::get('title'),
        'content' => Input::get('content')
        );
    $posts = new Post($post);
    $user->post()->save($post);

    dd($post);
}
```

Comment: one more thing! how can i protect routes from unauthorized users?

Comment: how can i view the content of users selected post in a diff page?                     <a href="{{ URL::route('viewPost', array('id' => $post->id))}}"> i started it here i dont know whats next ? or how to submit the id of the post to other page

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Maybe you should ask a new question and give some more detail?

Comment: uhm i posted the title of the post in dashboard, now what i want is to link the title of the post to view its content to other page ..

Comment: What you have looks good. Then your `viewPost` route only needs to have an `{id}` parameter and then you can use that in your controller.

Comment: throw new NotFoundHttpException;

Comment: Can you update the question with your `viewPost` route?

Comment: public function viewPost($id)
 {
  $this->layout->content = View::make('interface.viewPost', array('id' => $post->id));
 } is this the right? this is from my controller link to viewpost

Comment: and my routes Route::post('/Viewpost/{id}', array(
  'uses' => 'LoginUsersController@viewPost',
  'as' => 'viewPost'
  ));

Comment: use `Route::get()` instead of `post`

Comment: $post = Post::find($id); should i add this one in my controller? and pass it to the viewpage? cause im getting error undefined variable:post:

Comment: im getting this error i dont know where is this coming from "Undefined variable: post "

Comment: Even if you pass the post variable to the view?

Comment: hello lukasgeiter thank you so much i learn alot from you and i was able to solve the error in views! :) thanks alot

Comment: Hi, please ask a new question

Comment: Im sorry i posted that question here because i cant ask a question right now since i ask a question yesterday my account is restricted from asking another question. sorry

Comment: The problem is just that the comments are not a good place for new questions... Either wait til the restriction is lifted or create another account. But no matter what you do, think about why your account got restricted and try to do better in the future.